# checkbox save/load NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, checkbox

I have this app with two checkboxes that I want to save when I close and load when I open but I cannot figure it out. Please can someone help me edit the code. I know need to save in `UserDefaults` somehow but I don't know how to code it.

```
class CheckBox: UIButton {
    // Images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked")! as UIImage
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked")! as UIImage

    // Bool property
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == self {
            isChecked = !isChecked
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: move and shake http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/nsuserdefaults-example-in-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following to save bool value to UserDefaults:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(isChecked, forKey: "com.myCompany.checkboxState")
```

And load it using:

```
self.isChecked = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "com.myCompany.checkboxState")
```

Read more in documentation for [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults).

Just remember that if you have several checkBoxes, you have to use unique key for each one, e.g. use `UIButton`'s tag to differentiate between them:

```
class CheckBox: UIButton {
    // Images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked")! as UIImage
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked")! as UIImage

    // Bool property
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
            // save it like this
            UserDefaults.standard.set(isChecked, forKey: "com.myCompany.checkboxStateFor\(self.tag)")
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        // load it like this
        self.isChecked = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "com.myCompany.checkboxStateFor\(self.tag)")
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == self {
            isChecked = !isChecked
        }
    }

}
```

Then don't forget to setup a different tag for each checkBox in your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    isChecked = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "buttonChecked")
}

@objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    isChecked = !isChecked
    UserDefaults.standard.set(isChecked, forKey: "buttonChecked")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this you are looking for?

```
   extension UserDefaults{

    func setChecked(value: Bool, forId id: String){
        set(value, forKey: id)
    }

    func getChecked(forId id: String) -> Int{
        return bool(forKey: id)
    }
}
```

use:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setChecked(true, "box1")
UserDefaults.standard.getChecked("box1")
```